# Render form element of type text_format, keeping WYSYWIG format

Tags: theming

In Drupal 8 I have a form element fo type `text_format`, and I need to render it in a twig, but keeping the same format was entered in the WYSYWIG editor. I need to know how to render this element form, keeping the format? this its done in a custom form.

```
$form['template'] = [
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#title' => 'My title',
  '#rows' => 100,
  '#cols' => 120,
  '#format' => 'full_html',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is render it using the `#type => processed_text`. That's it, then you will see the element renderd keeping the format used in WYSYWIG.

```
$elements = [
  '#type' => 'processed_text',
  '#text' => $data,
  '#format' => 'full_html',
  '#langcode' => 'en',
];
```